# Efficient way of calculating similarity matrix for huge dataset in python

Tags: python, matrix, nltk, similarity

I am working on clustering of sentences using Affinity Propagation Clustering. As an intermediate step I am calculating similarity matrix. It works for small dataset but throws memory error for huge dataset. I have a dataset containing sentences.

Sample dataset:

```
'open contacts',
'open music player',
'play song',
'call john',
'open camera',
'video download',
...
```

My code:

```
import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import pandas as pd

punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
stemmer = nltk.stem.snowball.SpanishStemmer()

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(punctuation_map)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize)

def get_clusters(sentences):
    tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
    similarity_matrix = (tf_idf_matrix * tf_idf_matrix.T).A
    affinity_propagation = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
    affinity_propagation.fit(similarity_matrix)

#     global labels
    labels = affinity_propagation.labels_

#     global cluster_centers
    cluster_centers = affinity_propagation.cluster_centers_indices_

    tagged_sentences = zip(sentences, labels)
    clusters = {}

    for sentence, cluster_id in tagged_sentences:
        clusters.setdefault(sentences[cluster_centers[cluster_id]], []).append(sentence)
        #print(len(sentence))

    return clusters

#csv file
filename = "/home/ubuntu/VA_data/first_50K.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)

sentences = df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()

clusters = get_clusters(sentences)
```

Can anybody please suggest me efficient way of finding similarity matrix? My dataset contains 1 million sentences.

Comment: If you have a really big dataset / performance is important, take a look at [faiss library by facebook research](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss).

Comment: @umutto: I want use Affinity Propagation clustering only since we need not to specify number of clusters. I went through clustering method of faiss. It needs number of clusters.

Comment: You do know that AP clustering is one of the most time consuming one right? http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/performance_and_scalability.html

Comment: @alvas: ok. Which algorithm I should go for then?

Comment: Good question! But not one that can be answered from stackoverflow. IMHO, i'll try from the fastest to the slowest on the card from HDBScan. Then compare results from all possible algorithms that can give me the output within the time I'm willing to spend on each algorithm. I always start with K-means first =)

Comment: @alvas: Agree, but then how to decide number of clusters for other algorithms when you millions of data points?

Comment: That's when using Hierarchical Dirichlet Process would be helpful =) https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/hdpmodel.html

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to store the data in Spark which also provide scalable matrix multiplication.

Comment: I did even think about it but there is no function for Affinity Propagation clustering in Spark. I am firm on using Affinity Propagation clustering.